# Anesrake algorithm doesn't work with zero as a weight

Tags: r

I tried using the anesrake package, but it won't accept a weight of zero, giving the error message:

```
Error in while (range(weightvec)[2] > cap + 1e-04) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Sample code:

```
ipfdata<- read.csv("dummydata.csv", header = T)
ipfdata$caseid <- 1:length(ipfdata$age)
sex <- c(0.30, 0.70)
age <- c(0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.3, 0.2)
ses <- c(0.20, 0.20, 0.0)
targets <- list(sex, age, ses)
names(targets) <- c("sex", "age", "ses")
outsave <- anesrake(targets, ipfdata, caseid = ipfdata$caseid, weightvec = NULL, cap = 10, verbose = TRUE, maxit = 50, choosemethod = "total", type = "nolim", pctlim = 0.0001, nlim=10, iterate = T, force1 = TRUE)
```

(sample code modified from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458306/ipf-raking-using-anesrake-in-r-error)

Comment: It looks like you've set `weightvec` to be NULL. Is that what you mean by a "weight of zero"?

Comment: No, that's just the starting "guess" for the algorithm. You could just as easily leave it out. I'm referring specifically to the last weight in the `ses` vector c(0.20, 0.20, 0.0)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the algorithm being implemented here, but simply stepping through the code, at some point various values in `weightvec` are being set to `NaN`, and the `range` call isn't adequately safeguarded against that. Based on your previous question and this one, I'm not terribly impressed with the code in that package. The use of `eval(parse())` noted in the previous question is particularly egregious. I'd be wary of using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package was never updated despite my contacting the author to address this issue. The only workaround is to remove any rows with the variable set to zero before raking.

In the given sample above, you would have to remove any rows with the third SES factor, and then change the SES vector to `c(0.20, 0.20)` instead of `c(0.20, 0.20, 0.0)`.

Comment: I don't know if this is more or less by design of the algorithm. see https://edyhsgr.github.io/IPFDescription/AKDOLWDIPFTWOD.pdf on " 2 more important points